# how to find hard drive brand name or model?

Tags: hard-drive

I am using xubuntu 14.04. I need to know the manufacturer name of the internal hard drive or similar information.

For example when using windows we can see the manufacturer information of the hard drives and other devices in the device manager. Is something similar available in Ubuntu for hard drives ?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/how-to-see-disk-details-like-manufacturer-in-linux

Answer (score 37):

Ubuntu comes with `UDisks2` library, which provides [udisks daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks) and couple command-line tools to query disk information and otherwise manipulate the drives. In particular, `udisksctl status` command is useful if you want to find out the information without root privileges locally.

```
$ udisksctl  status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CHN 25SATA01M 030         P0527A    30CG09180078         sda     
Radeon R7                 1.01      A22MD061520000172    sdb
```

Udisk2 provides D-Bus interface, so if you ever want to use that in your own scripts or applications - it's possible. An example of that would be my own  [disk usage indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/830558/295286).

Another way is via [`udevadm`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udevadm.html) management utility for [udev subsystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev).

```
$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda1 | grep 'ID_MODEL='
E: ID_MODEL=CHN_25SATA01M_030
```

Alternative and indirect way is to identify the filesystem stored on the drive by [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,UUID
NAME   UUID
sda    
└─sda1 8e73e463-fef8-4119-b826-00e74eb4192c
sdb    
└─sdb1 86df21bf-d95f-435c-9292-273bdbcba056

$ sudo blkid /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for user: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="8e73e463-fef8-4119-b826-00e74eb4192c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="73e878a1-01"
```

Other methods that contain such info:

- `sudo parted -l`
- `cat /sys/block/sda/device/model`

Comment: Why there is Radeon R7 on the list?

Answer (score 24):

You can use `lshw`.

Install it by running `sudo apt-get install lshw` from Terminal (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), if not installed already.

Then from Terminal you can run:

```
$ sudo lshw -C disk
  *-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST9500325AS
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 0003
       serial: 6VEEA06N
       size: 465GiB (500GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=0007006e
```

All information about your hard drive will be shown, you can use it for checking any other hardware's details too. See [`man lshw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/lshw.1.html) for more info.

Answer (score 14):

Go to the Dash and search for "Disks". You should see one application with that exact name. Open it to get the info you need.

[image: Screeny]

Answer (score 5):

Here is another option:

Run in the terminal:

```
       sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep Serial
```

You will get an output like this:

```
     Serial Number:      WD-WCAYUV308920
     Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, 
     SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
```

Comment: I like this answer that doesn't require installation of addition package.